# WIth Vimeo Plus account, how to hide/remove the "play" button in the middle of an embedded video?

Tags: api, vimeo

In searching, I came across this that says Vimeo doesn't support it yet. But I was wondering if anyone has found clever ways around it still?

https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:37769

Here's an image:

[image]

Answer (score 50):

#### You can now remove all controls

just wanted to update anyone new looking at this.
It now appears to be possible to have an embeded video without any of the controls, by using an experimental feature: `background=1`

#### Things to note

1. All player toggles and elements will be turned off (including the play/pause button!)
2. The video will automatically loop.
3. The video will be set to autoplay.
4. The video will be muted.

you can then use the [js-api](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) to control the video (pause, play, etc).

#### Example Embed Code

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?background=1" 
   width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen 
   mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

See the forum post here: https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:278001

Comment: To hide the UI in the player without muting/autoplaying/looping you can use "?controls=0"

Comment: This works only for background videos which are muted.

Answer (score 6):

**2020 answer**

For embed video player you can use parameters `?controls=0` or `?pip=0`

If you use [Vimeo SDK](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk):

Set **controls** option to **false**

```js
var options = {
    id: '116582567',
    width: '800',
    controls: false
}

Player = new Vimeo.Player('video', options);
Player.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<div id="video"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Vimeo account go to the video you wish to embed, then go to Settings > Embed.  Once there enable the "Show Play Bar" option.  This will eliminate the Play button in the middle of your video image, but will display the Play Bar at the bottom of your image.  From what I can tell it's either/or.  I would love to be able to hide both so you just see the clean poster frame of the video and click on it ti initiate playback.  If anyone knows how please let me know.

Comment: As a result of reading this I looked into the issue further and found several posts on Vimeo's own forum where staff members state there is no plan to allow hiding the play button, (https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:43217). I think it is disingenuous of Vimeo to advertise a custom player at a premium price and then insist on enforcing an element of their own branding (there play button). They do offer the option to use a third party player, but why pay for a premium service and then have to implement and maintain your own player. Thanks for saving me the cost of pro membership to find this out.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this isn't against the Vimeo rules, but it is possible to hide those buttons.

```
<!-- Video original height is 280px -->
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #wrapper {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 560px;   /* height x 2 */
    }
    #wrapper iframe {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: -140px;  /* video height / 2 */
    }
</sytle>


<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="player1" 
        src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/83762493?loop=1&autoplay=1" 
        width="500" height="560" <!-- vide height x 2 -->
        frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This *is* against the Vimeo API Terms of Service. Source: http://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:37579#comment_5217040

Comment: Also you where going to loose video parts

Comment: @Bill dead link, do you know where I can find that?

Comment: Seems it's here https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/terms "3.4: You will not alter, remove, replace, or mask any aspect of the Vimeo Player (including the playbar, logo, and like, embed, and share features) without our prior written consent."

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Settings of the video, then to Distribution > Video File Links. Then copy one of the formats links, for example `Standard def`.

[image]
[image]