# I am trying to remove vimeo player play/pause button. But its not removed. If any body there ideas

Tags: css, vimeo

what is the solution for remove play and pause button in vimeo player?

**for css**

```
.controls{
    display:none;
}
```

I will try it. But no response.

Comment: This might be helpful to you, while getting the embed code you can select what (this way](https://zaption.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204445495-How-can-I-remove-the-controls-from-my-Vimeo-video-)

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432087/with-vimeo-plus-account-how-to-hide-remove-the-play-button-in-the-middle-of-a

Comment: Hey there . This is ok  but, its not supporting for responsive .

Comment: It's now possible...check this new answer if your'e still interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34047998/1097858